# Why computer didn't use cesium atom to define 1 second?

Tags: clocks, real-time

As far I know computer using crystal oscilator to define 1 second and it's not real 1 second, i mean it's not stable.

While real clock using cesium and we know cesium is stable, why doesn't computer contain cesium in its component to define 1 second.

So thats mean 1 second in clock atom and 1 second in computer are not syncreon, even 1 second at between two computers are not syncreon each other.

What I mean with computer is not only advanced computer device like personal computer, this applied to microcontroller.

Instead of using atom cesium, they are using Internet Protocol especially `Network Time Protocol (NTP)`

I'm wonder is there fatal effect from asyncreon of computer time like maybe airport schedule or what if they didn't use NTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the reason personal computers dont't use atomic clocks based on caesium is price. One [CSAC (chip scale atomic clock)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip-scale_atomic_clock) costs 5000 USD nowadays. The added precision is not worth the price for the normal consumer.
However there are cases where the time synchronization via NTP combined with a crystal oscillator are not precise enough.
For example missiles that rely on GPS to determine their location / find their target use CSACs to get much higher GPS precision.
Other applications are for example radar, or scientific measurements.